# PyRevit should be supported in Design Automation for Revit

Tags: autodesk-forge

We would to know if PyRevit is supported in Design Automation for Revit. Can we elaborate on that?

We need to control that so we can make some changes on the bottom toolbar in the Models.

How we can manage this? Please provide us with more explanation.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

No, sorry. However, [pyRevit is open source](https://github.com/eirannejad/pyRevit), so you can grab the bits of functionality that you require and integrate those into your Design Automation app, if you like, provided you comply with the license requirements.